# Horizontally align the navbar using nextjs and tailwind css

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

Hello How can I horzontally align my navbar

```
    <nav className='flex items-stretch flex-wrap bg-blue-300 p-3 '>
      <div className='flex px-4 align-middle'>
        <Link href = '/'>
          <a>The Falcon's Fury</a>
        </Link>
        </div>
      
      <div className="flex justify-center">   
        <div className="mb-3 xl:w-96">
          <div className="input-group relative flex flex-wrap
          items-stretch w-full mb-4"> 
            <input type="search" className ="form-control relative flex-auto 
             min-w-0 block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 
            bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded 
            transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 
            focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none" 
            placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria- 
             describedby="button-addon3"></input>
            <button className="btn inline-block px-6 py-2 border-2 border-blue-600 
           text-blue-600 font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase 
           rounded hover:bg-black hover:bg-opacity-5 focus:outline-none 
            focus:ring-0 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" type="button" 
             id="button-addon3">Search</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

  </nav>
```

The above code dispalys like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|Falcons Fury Input field                                           |
|             Search                                                |
|                                                                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But the desired outcome should be

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|Falcons Fury          Input field Search                           |
|                                                                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried going through https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items and applying but it does not work out

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, You can added `flex-wrap` class to `div` which holds your `input` and `button`. Replace with below code,

```
   <nav class='flex items-stretch flex-wrap bg-blue-300 p-3 '>
      <div class='flex px-4 align-middle'>
        <Link href = '/'>
          <a>The Falcon's Fury</a>
        </Link>
        </div>
      
      <div class="flex justify-center">   
        <div class="mb-3 xl:w-96">
          <div class="input-group relative flex items-stretch w-full mb-4"> 
            <input type="search" class ="form-control relative flex-auto 
             min-w-0 block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 
            bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded 
            transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 
            focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none" 
            placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria- 
             describedby="button-addon3"></input>
            <button class="btn inline-block px-6 py-2 border-2 border-blue-600 
           text-blue-600 font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase 
           rounded hover:bg-black hover:bg-opacity-5 focus:outline-none 
            focus:ring-0 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" type="button" 
             id="button-addon3">Search</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

You are new to stackoverflow. Please don't add unnecessary tags like `next-js` to your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `flex-direction:row` to the div containing input and button. Below is the code.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<nav class='flex items-stretch flex-wrap bg-blue-300 p-3 '>
  <div class='flex px-4 align-middle'>
    <Link href = '/'>
      <a>The Falcon's Fury</a>
    </Link>
  </div>
      
  <div class="flex  justify-center">   
    <div class="mb-3 xl:w-96">
      <div class="input-group relative flex flex-row space-x-4
          items-stretch w-full mb-4"> 
        <input type="search" class ="form-control relative flex-auto 
             min-w-0 block w-full px-3 py-1.5 text-base font-normal text-gray-700 
            bg-white bg-clip-padding border border-solid border-gray-300 rounded 
            transition ease-in-out m-0 focus:text-gray-700 
            focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none" 
            placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" aria- 
             describedby="button-addon3"></input>
        <button class="btn inline-block px-6 py-2 border-2 border-blue-600 
           text-blue-600 font-medium text-xs leading-tight uppercase 
           rounded hover:bg-black hover:bg-opacity-5 focus:outline-none 
            focus:ring-0 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" type="button" 
             id="button-addon3">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```